# AFNetworking: parsing xml in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, afnetworking, nsxmlparser

I think I am on the right track, but just wanted to double check here. I recently started using AFNetworking to obtain a large XML file from a database, which I then need to parse (I got that part all figured out). I would like the parsing to happen on a background thread, and then update my UI on the main thread. So I added another dispatch_async block inside the success block of the AFXMLRequestOperation:

```
self.xmlOperation =
[AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest: request
                                                    success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {

                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                                                             XMLParser.delegate = self;
                                                            [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
                                                            [XMLParser parse];

                                                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                [self.searchResultViewController didFinishImport];
                                                                [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

                                                            });
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                    failure: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
                                                        // show error
                                                    }];

[self.xmlOperation start];
```

Is the the proper/correct/preferred way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty good. Two observations, though:

1. Does any of your code on the main thread can access any of the objects actively being updated by your `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods? If not, you're fine.

   But, if you have any code (driving the UI, for example) that is accessing the same objects/collections that the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods are updating, then you have to be careful about synchronizing those shared resources. (For more information about synchronizing resources, see the [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) section of the *Threading Programming Guide* and/or the [Eliminating Lock Based Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) section of the *Concurrency Programming Guide.*)

   Personally, I like to move the `NSXMLParserDelegate` code into a separate class, and instantiate that for the individual request, that way I know that my request and subsequent parsing process can never be a source of synchronization issues. You still need to synchronize the update model/store process, but you are effectively doing that by performing that final update on the main queue.
2. Does your UI allow you to issue another XML request while the first one is in progress? If not, you're fine.

   If the user can initiate second request while the first is in progress, it opens you up to the (admittedly unlikely) scenario that you could two concurrent processing requests using the same instance of the delegate object. Clearly, you could solve this by preventing subsequent requests until the first one finished (e.g. disable UI elements that request refresh), or use a serial queue, or move the parser into a separate class that you'll instantiate for every request. Personally, I'd be inclined to make make this parse request cancelable and make the issuance of a new request cancel any prior, on-going ones.

Those are two concurrency-related issues as I look at your code sample. Perhaps neither of these are, in fact, an issue with your particular implementation. Having said that, the very fact that the code is so contingent on the rest of your implementation is, itself, an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input Rob. In fact neither two observations you describe are an issue in my case. Also, I do my parsing in a separate class (more or less following the Conway/Hillegass approach in their iOS book), but just removed that for the clarity of this example.

Comment: I'm actually running in an issue with Magical Record. As stated here https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/298, I cannot use MR_createEntity on a background thread. And creating entities using MR_createEntity is exactly what I was doing while parsing the XML. So I need to rethink that strategy.

Comment: @Koen Ah, ok. I didn't know what you were doing in the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods. Perhaps parse the XML into some collection (whatever the appropriate combination of nested arrays and dictionaries are for your data), and then have the code that you post back to the main queue take that structure and do the Magical Record stuff. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, and I think this will help me with that: http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/  But this is outside this topic, so I'll create a new one if needed :)

Comment: And for the curious, that new topic is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543739/using-magicalrecord-and-nsxmlparser-in-a-background-thread